# What was this holder, made from paper, used for?

Tags: paper

I found this is at the house of a deceased relative (IOW asking the former owner is not possible for obvious, sad, reasons).

I slid a "Get out of jail free" card into it to illustrate what I guess it was used for (holding something thin, but what?).

[image: Holder with card slid in]

The 2nd picture shows it disassembled. The 2 (formerly probably white) thin cardboard pieces give it some stability.
[image: disassembled]

Putting the 2 thin cardboard pieces back was not so easy, so I wonder how this was mass produced (it doesn't look like a one-off piece to me; the cuts are very clean and parallel).

It was with a pile of papers, estimated to be at least 30 years old.

Searching the net didn't give any leads, but that could be my poor google-fu (though I saw a lot of interesting origami projects in the last hour LOL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember seeing these things.  My recollection is that it was just a novel card wallet (for up to four cards). Weaving a card through the strips holds it in place, and the alternating strips let you see what the card is without needing a transparent pocket. Weave in reverse on the two sections to hold the strips together.

Two cards back-to-back in each middle section lets you view each from opposite sides. Folding it up makes it not much bigger than a single card. It keeps them together, and the outside sections protect the cards. It's something fun and functional you can make from paper.

The strips in the middle can be cut with scissors; they don't need to be perfect.  Fold the paper in half and then fold the sides in half.  Unfold the sides, leaving the sheet still folded in half.  Use the crease as a stopping guide when you cut the strips in the middle section starting from the folded edge.

Comment: Oh, the thin cardboard pieces are supposed to be removed? Their sizes are 9 cm (3.5 in) by 6.2 cm (a bit under 2.5 in). Business cards seem to be about that height but not that wide, so indeed easier to weave trough than those cardboard pieces.

Comment: (Didn't know Enter sends the comment and editing is limited to 5 min.)

Because those placeholders are so tight fitting, I assumed there was some product held in place there (it was next to a sewing machine, which could be a red herring). But if that was containing some commercially sold product the blueish paper should have some product description, shouldn't it? 

BTW: Yesterday I found some notes nearby from 1967 to 1969! (another red herring LOL?)

Your explanation seems to be the most likely, I'll take that as an answer in about 2 weeks (hoping for more ideas in the meantime ;-)

Comment: @w2013, as long as the cardboard inserts plus your cards fit, they can be left in place, with cards in front on either side. That can make it more stable, & easier to accommodate smaller cards. You can make these for any size cards; just start with paper trimmed to the right size. It's unusual, so attention-getting, and easy to make. Anyone could have used the idea, added printing to the folder, etc. if they wanted. It could be a memorable way to bundle something like a business card with other card-sized stuff, a cute gift card, or just a novelty to keep kids entertained. Simpler times.  :-)